# Writing MQTT data to influxdb via python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, influxdb

I am trying to write some sensor data to influxdb using a python script.

The sensor is sending data and my Mosquitto broker is picking it up:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mosquitto_sub -u pi -P ******* -v -t '#'
insideroom/temperature temp,site=PrintingRoom value=20.83
insideroom/humidity humidity,site=PrintingRoom value=59.90
```

I've been following this guide: https://diyi0t.com/visualize-mqtt-data-with-influxdb-and-grafana/
and modified the script they've used slightly as my MQTT topic is different.

This is the output from the script:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 room-monitor-grafana-v2.py
MQTT to InfluxDB bridge
Connected with result code 0
Connected to Broker
insideroom/temperature b'temp,site=PrintingRoom value=20.32'
<re.Match object; span=(0, 22), match='insideroom/temperature'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/room-monitor-grafana-v2.py", line 100, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/room-monitor-grafana-v2.py", line 95, in main
    mqtt_client.loop_forever()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1756, in loop_forever
    rc = self._loop(timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1164, in _loop
    rc = self.loop_read()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1556, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2439, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3033, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_publish()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3327, in _handle_publish
    self._handle_on_message(message)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3570, in _handle_on_message
    on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
  File "/home/pi/room-monitor-grafana-v2.py", line 45, in on_message
    sensor_data = _parse_mqtt_message(msg.topic, msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
  File "/home/pi/room-monitor-grafana-v2.py", line 56, in _parse_mqtt_message
    measurement = match.group(2)
IndexError: no such group
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""A MQTT to InfluxDB Bridge
This script receives MQTT data and saves those to InfluxDB.
"""

import re
from typing import NamedTuple

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

INFLUXDB_ADDRESS = '*****'
INFLUXDB_USER = '******'
INFLUXDB_PASSWORD = '******'
INFLUXDB_DATABASE = '*******'

MQTT_ADDRESS = '*******'
MQTT_USER = 'pi'
MQTT_PASSWORD = '*******'
MQTT_TOPIC = 'insideroom/#'  
MQTT_REGEX = 'insideroom/([^/]+)'

influxdb_client = InfluxDBClient(INFLUXDB_ADDRESS, 8086, None)


class SensorData(NamedTuple):
    location: str
    measurement: str
    value: float


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    """ The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server."""
    print('Connected with result code ' + str(rc))
    if rc ==0:
        print("Connected to Broker")
        client.subscribe('insideroom/humidity')
        client.subscribe('insideroom/temperature')


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    """The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server."""
    print(msg.topic + ' ' + str(msg.payload))
    sensor_data = _parse_mqtt_message(msg.topic, msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    print(sensor_data)
    if sensor_data is not None:
        _send_sensor_data_to_influxdb(sensor_data)


def _parse_mqtt_message(topic, payload):
    match = re.match(MQTT_REGEX, topic)
    print(match)
    if match:
        location = match.group(1)
        measurement = match.group(2)
        if measurement == 'status':
            return None
        return SensorData(location, float(payload))
    else:
        return None


def _send_sensor_data_to_influxdb(sensor_data):
    json_body = [
        {
            'measurement': sensor_data.measurement,
            'tags': {
                'location': sensor_data.location
            },
            'fields': {
                'value': sensor_data.value
            }
        }
    ]
    influxdb_client.write_points(json_body)


def _init_influxdb_database():
    databases = influxdb_client.get_list_database()
    if len(list(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == INFLUXDB_DATABASE, databases))) == 0:
        influxdb_client.create_database(INFLUXDB_DATABASE)
    influxdb_client.switch_database(INFLUXDB_DATABASE)


def main():
    _init_influxdb_database()

    mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
    mqtt_client.username_pw_set(MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD)
    mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
    mqtt_client.on_message = on_message

    mqtt_client.connect(MQTT_ADDRESS, 1883)
    mqtt_client.loop_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('MQTT to InfluxDB bridge')
    main()
```

Do I need to pass the message through the function _parse_mqtt_message or can it be written straight to influx? If you have any sources to point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated too!

Comment: You expect a `group(2)` with only one pair of parentheses?

Comment: Please aim for a [**minimal**, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I believe your question could probably be reduced to "why does `print(re.match("insideroom/([^/]+)", "insideroom/temperature").group(2))` fail with error..."